# Wicked PDF + Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip, wicked-pdf

Im having a huge problem, that i cant figure it out.

Im trying to generate a page in a show action:

```
# projects_controller.rb

def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render  :pdf => "#{@project.id}-#{@project.name}",
                :template => 'projects/show.pdf.erb',
                :layout => 'layouts/pdf.html.erb',
                :encoding => "utf-8",
                :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?
      end
    end
end
```

But, in this view i have some uploaded files via paperclip and when i try to enter http://localhost:3000/projects/1.pdf e.g. it throw a error:

```
Sprockets::FileOutsidePaths in Projects#show

Showing /Users/victorrodrigues/Sites/ror/linhadefrente/app/views/projects/show.pdf.erb where line #342 raised:

/system/upload/platforms/14/icon/small/revista.png?2011 isn't in paths:    /Users/victorrodrigues/Sites/ror/linhadefrente/app/assets/fontface, /Users/victorrodrigues/Sites/ror/linhadefrente/app/assets/images, /Users/victorrodrigues/Sites/ror/linhadefrente/app/assets/javascripts, /Users/victorrodrigues/Sites/ror/linhadefrente/app/assets/stylesheets, /Users/victorrodrigues/Sites/ror/linhadefrente/vendor/assets/stylesheets, /Users/victorrodrigues/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@linhadefrente/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.14/vendor/assets/javascripts, /Users/victorrodrigues/Sites/ror/linhadefrente/app/assets/fontface, /Users/victorrodrigues/Sites/ror/linhadefrente/public/system
```

I tryed to add the "system" path:

```
# application.rb
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/public/system"
```

But i dont know how to fix this, anyone can help, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a gem incompatibility issue.

Try `gem "sprockets", "2.0"`

Refer [LINK](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/214) for more details.

Comment: Well, i cant use sprockets 2.0 since im using rails 3.1.1 which depends on sprockets 2.0.2. I was using the version 2.0.3 and doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

If you already have sprockets 2.0 or greater, and you moved the folder that holds the file you are referring to (for example I moved my template folder from javascripts to assets) it is probably just a cache issue. I rebooted my computer and it worked fine.